# Setup Postfix to send email to same domain as server

Tags: linux, php, debian, postfix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Postfix deliver mails locally instead of relaying them to Google Apps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301280/why-does-postfix-deliver-mails-locally-instead-of-relaying-them-to-google-apps)

I have a `Debian Linux` server setup on `Linode`. I am using `Postfix` for mail and have set it for myrealdomain.com.

Some of the pages on my site have a php form, that when filled out gets sent to my email address, which is also at myrealdomain.com. I am using Google Apps for my email.

For some reason, I assume since it is sending to the same domain, I never get the email. Changing it to send to my gmail account does work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: [Why does Postfix deliver mails locally instead of relaying them to Google Apps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301280/why-does-postfix-deliver-mails-locally-instead-of-relaying-them-to-google-apps)

It would look like that in your `main.cf` file:

```
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost
fallback_transport = relay
```

Comment: That's horrible; you're basically providing an open relay to whomever manages to send mail to your server. Please consult the documentation for fallback_transport: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#fallback_transport

Comment: Ok, instead of criticizing, why not help out someone who doesn't know much about postfix? I didn't realize this was a bad idea. Looking at the fallback_transport docu doesn't give me a clue as to what I need to change.

Comment: Please provide the output of `postconf -n` and relevant logs that show what is happening that you don't want to be happening.

Comment: Well adding the above fixed my problem. But you said that this is a bad idea. So now I am wondering how I can still having it working how it is, but not have a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since your domain is hosted at gmail, why are you using postfix at all ?

A simple (and secure) local nullmailer would suffice for web forms.

Comment: I am using a CMS. Which requires something like postfix.

Comment: A bit more detail than "something like postfix" would be useful.

Comment: All I meant was that my CMS requires postfix or sendmail to be setup in order to send mail. I am using postfix. So that is why I assume it is a postfix config option I need to change?